# Electron - How to share a single promise resolution from Main to multiple Renderers?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm new to Electron and trying to figure out the best way to handle a shared object.

Essentially, I want to initialize something once in the Main process, then use it in multiple renderer processes, like so:

```
// main.js
const node = rosnodejs.initNode(); // returns a promise

// renderer1.js
node.then((nh) => {
  nh.subscribe("topic1");
})

// renderer2.js
node.then((nh) => {
  nh.subscribe("topic2");
})
```

I was able to share `node` using `remote`, but then `nh.subscribe` becomes an anonymous function in my renderers and fails. Here's what I'm doing:

```
// main.js
global.node = rosnodejs.initNode(); // returns a promise
global.node.then((nh) => {
  nh.subscribe("topic1");  // WORKS PERFECTLY!
})

// renderer1.js
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const node = remote.getGlobal('node');
node.then((nh) => {
  nh.subscribe("topic2"); // FAILS MISERABLY.
})
```

Failure message is `Error: Could not call remote function 'subscribe'. Check that the function signature is correct. Underlying error: type.datatype is not a function`.

Is there a decent way to handle this? Should I be using `ipcMain`/`ipcRenderer` instead?

Comment: use IPC, instead of doing this

Comment: This seems like a bad eyed deer.

Comment: @TinyGiant can you elaborate?

Comment: Generally the use of remote should be avoided as much as humanly possible. I would recommend reading [api/remote.md](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md) for more information. Regardless, you aren't sending objects between processes even with `remote`. _"When you invoke methods of a remote object, call a remote function, or create a new object with the remote constructor (function), you are actually sending synchronous inter-process messages"_. The object's enumerable properties are shallow-copied to a new object on the target, and context is not preserved.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I'll follow a singleton promise architecture (https://medium.com/tomincode/singleton-promises-c750dc40eaa7) and then write IPC requests to get the promise from each renderer. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing something but I don't see how that would help you. You can't pass promise objects between processes any more than you can pass any other object between processes. The only real way to get close is to `require` the object constructor in both processes,  then pass the information required to construct equivalent objects through IPC.

Comment: As a side note, if you want me to be notified of your responses you need to `@ping` me. See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for more info on that.

Comment: @TinyGiant (That should work as a notification, right?)

I didn't realize that IPC was only sending serialized data, not the full objects themselves, so I (obviously) can't call the methods of the object post-serialization. I don't want to call `initNode` more than once, so I don't think I can `require` the object constructor in both processes. Would it be possible for both `main` and `renderer` to require the object itself in both processes?

Comment: The node context is not shared between renderer and main, so `require` would execute the target script once in either process, each would get it's own instance. [NW.js allows you to use common Node.js contexts](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/JavaScript%20Contexts%20in%20NW.js/), but I don't have any experience implementing that, and you woulding be ditching Electron entirely, so there's that...

Answer (score 0):

If someone happens to stumble across this (pretty old) question, here is what you can do. Remote is outdated and deemed unsecure, so you should use ipc messages and simply await a promise that listens for the response from the renderer. So in the main process it could be a function that looks like this.

```
async sendToRendererAndWaitForAnswer<T>(
    yourData: unknown,
    timeout: number,
  ): Promise<T> {
    this.mainWindow.webContents.send('to-renderer-message', yourData)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const listener: ElectronListener = (event, { response }) => {
        ipcMain.removeListener('to-main-message', listener)
        resolve(response)
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        ipcMain.removeListener('to-main-message', listener)
        reject(new Error('Timeout reached waiting for message'))
      }, timeout)
      ipcMain.on('to-main-message', listener)
    })
  }
```